# No option for Git in New Team Project

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

When attempting to create a New Team Project in Visual Studio 2015, there is no option for source control with Git. The only option present is Team Foundation Version Control.

[image: New Team Project dialog box]

Most tutorials seem to have an option for Git:

[image: Yay for Git]

Comment: Have you configured your Git locally?  Can you open the Git bash?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I ran the installer off of the [git-scm](http://www.git-scm.com/downloads) download page, but I haven't done anything else.

Comment: Git needs to be configured before it will work.  Unless you expect Visual Studio to do this (I doubt it will), you will have to do it yourself.  Most likely, Visual Studio cannot detect Git, so it is not appearing in the drop down menu.  Visual Studio 2013 and later supposedly ships with the Git plugin, so the plugin should not be the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS 2012 is not support GIT team project(repositories), GIT team project is a new feature which released from TFS 2013, so you need upgrade to TFS 2013 or TFS 2015 to create the GIT team project.

Answer (score 0):

Before TFS 2015 Update 1, you could not mix TFVC in the same team project collection.  Have you installed update 1?

Comment: I believe the server is running on TFS 2012. Is this the problem? Do I need to upgrade to TFS 2015?

Comment: Yes, you will need to update to TFS 2015 Update 1 if you want to mix TFVC and GIT in the same team project collection.

Comment: Actually, this is a brand new collection that I wanted to use for Git.

Comment: Looks like GIT source control was released in TFS 2013 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx